# Evaluate $(1+i)^{(1-2i)}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Find all the values of $(1+i)^{(1-2i)}$ and show that there are small values as we wish (else from $0$) and big values as we wish

\begin{align} 
(1+i)^{(1-2i)}&=e^{\ln(1+i)^{(1-2i)}}
=e^{(1-2i)\ln(1+i)}
\\&=e^{(\ln\sqrt{2}+i(\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi k))(1-2i)}
\\&=e^{\ln\sqrt{2}-2\ln\sqrt{2}*i+i(\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi k)+2(\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi k))}
\\&=\sqrt{2}*e^{-2\ln\sqrt{2}*i}*i*e^{2(\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi k)}
\\&=e^{-2\ln\sqrt{2}*i+\pi+4\pi k}+i\sqrt{2}
\\&=e^{-i(2\ln\sqrt{2}+i(\pi+4\pi k))}+i\sqrt{2}
\\&=e^{-i}*e^{(2\ln\sqrt{2}+i(\pi+4\pi k))}+i\sqrt{2}
\\&=\frac{3}{4}*e^{(2\ln\sqrt{2}+i(\pi+4\pi k))}+i\sqrt{2}
\\&=\frac{3}{4}*2e^{i(\pi+4\pi k)}+i\sqrt{2}
\\&=\frac{-3}{2}+i\sqrt{2}
\end{align}

What can I conclude from it on the values?

Or should I stop here $e^{-2\ln\sqrt{2}*i+\pi+4\pi k}+i\sqrt{2}$ and $e^{\pi+4 \pi k}cis(-2\ln\sqrt{2}+\frac{\pi}{2})$

Comment: This is quite difficult to read. Consider using `\begin{align}` and `\end{align}`.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire added

Comment: In line 7 you used the wrong formula $e^{-iz}=e^{-i}e^{z}$.

Comment: Somehow along the way (line 4->5) one multiplication mutated into an addition. You should not get a sum from your formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. Note that $|e^z|=|e^{\text{Re}(z)+i\text{Im}(z)}|=e^{\text{Re}(z)}$, hence here we are interested in (see your third step where the correct argument of $(1+i)$ is $\pi/4+2\pi k$)
$$\text{Re}(\ln\sqrt{2}+i(\frac{\pi}{4}+2\pi k))(1-2i))=\ln\sqrt{2}+\pi\left(4k+\frac{1}{2}\right)$$
where $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Now consider the limits as $k\to \pm \infty$.

Comment: Should it be $\ln\sqrt{2}+\pi (4k+\frac{1}{2})$?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

There should only be one value.$$(1+i)^{1-2i}=(\sqrt 2e^\dfrac{i\pi}{4})^{1-2i}=\sqrt 2e^\dfrac{i\pi}{4}(0.5e^\dfrac{-i\pi}{2})^i=\sqrt 2e^\dfrac{\pi}{2}e^{i(\dfrac{\pi}{4}+\ln 0.5)}$$

Comment: There is not. $ $

Comment: What you said means that $(\dfrac{1}{2})^i$ should have different values. Why should it be so?

Comment: You should be the one telling us why -- or why you choose to answer questions on subjects you obviously do not master?

Comment: Wooow not so fast! If one quantity or expression is multivalued one must say why is that so not the one ascribing only one variable to it, for example nobody asks why $2^2$ has only one value but if somebody claims another value he should explain.

Comment: Yes, "so fast". You may not be realizing it but, posting this, you are squarely ignoring the basics of the domain (call it "complex analysis" if you wish). Again, **you** should explain why **you** see fit to post **wrong** answers.